# Why not name all files .php instead of .html

Tags: php, html

If someone could point out what I'm missing here, that would be appreciated

I'm new but I haven't encountered a situation where wrongly naming a html file as php can be bad.

Perhaps it's just less confusing for developers?

Comment: Please further express the problem and question. Tks

Comment: Why use a system that assumes one file = one page?

Comment: @Quentin PHP doesn't require that...

Comment: @Izkata — It doesn't, but the system is very likely to be assuming that if you can happily with between .html and .php file extensions.

Comment: I don't think should have been closed as opinion based - there are some very concrete reasons why needlessly changing the file extension will cause issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP files are sent to be evaluated after the browser requests them whereas HTML files are directly given to the browser.

So if there is no PHP code in your .php file, you are still sending it to be evaluated, though it doesn't do much to the loading time of the page, if anything.

Comment: Not sure about this, because we can embed php code into html files and it works fine, even if file extension is .html.

Comment: Then the server is probably configured to send all files to the PHP module even if the extension is not .php. It's a general server configuration, but if your extension is .html and that config is not set up, the embedded PHP code will not run

Answer (score 12):

If you've a web server that understands the .php file extension and has the necessary PHP module installed, there's no issue with simply renaming a .html file to .php (as long as all links to it are also renamed accordingly).

However there's *absolutely* no benefit in doing this (and I'd dispute any meaningful UX benefit from the user's perspective), as it'll mean that the web server will need to invoke the PHP module to parse the file. This will be a waste of time and memory, as it's just a plain HTML file.

Comment: I disagree if you have other PHP pages. The time and memory used is so miniscule that it is unnoticable. However to send a user navigating around multiple extensions I think is confusing.

Comment: My question is when we embed php code in html file, it works fine, ie the code is run even if file extension is .html. Why is that ?

Comment: @GeorgeReith I'm pretty sure you'd change your mind if you ever had to performance tune a server to handle high loads. The "miniscule" adds up pretty quickly.

Comment: @altafhussain This is because the admin of your web server has configured it to parse the .html extension via the PHP module - this is by no means a standard approach. N.B.: You should create your own question on StackOverflow, rather than hijack someone else's.

Comment: @middaparka If I was that worried about performance I would be using some form of server-side cache, and avoid sending the page to be evaluated anyway.

Comment: @GeorgeReith True, but you don't always have the time/code to use Varnish, memcached, etc., etc. That said, I take your point. (Although if you were *really* worried about performance, you probably wouldn't be using PHP in the first place.) ;-)

Comment: @middaparka Indeed, I wouldn't normally show file extensions to the user anyway but in this case I assumed they are and that this makes for slightly better UX. It depends what your priority is I guess.

Comment: @middaparka , dont know how you call it hijacking. Just asked a question about your answer from you so that it is more clear. Is it not allowed to do so ?